# GitHub Actions `HttpError: Not Found` when initializing new deployment for develop @ refs/heads/develop

Tags: github-actions, vercel

I have a GitHub repo (let's call it `my-repo`), with GitHub Actions set up and the corresponding .github/workflows/files.yml included, and properly linked to Vercel.  When my deployment Action runs, it fails with an HttpError and this log:

1. `Run bobheadxi/deployments@v1`
2. `targeting my-GitHub/my-repo`
3. `initializing new deployment for develop @ refs/heads/develop`
4. `unexpected error encountered: HttpError: Not Found`
5. `Error: unexpected error encountered: HttpError: Not Found`

I have confirmed that `refs/heads/develop` exists in my-repo's refs.

Here is a screenshot of the GitHub Actions log (with debugging enabled):
[image: screenshot of GitHub Actions log]

Here is my workflow code (Point of failure is `Create Deployment`):

```
name: Deploy Environment to Vercel

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
      - main
      - release
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  deploy_develop:
    name: "Deploy to Develop"
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop'
    runs-on: mono-runner
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Create Deployment
    uses: bobheadxi/deployments@v1
    id: deployment
    with:
      step: start
      token: ${{ secrets.BUILDBOT_PERSONAL_TOKEN }}
      env: "Develop" 

  - name: Vercel Deployment
    uses: amondnet/vercel-action@master
    id: vercel
    with:
      vercel-token: ${{ secrets.BUILDBOT_VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      github-token: ${{ secrets.BUILDBOT_PERSONAL_TOKEN }}
      vercel-org-id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}
      vercel-project-id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID }}
      scope: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}

  - name: Update Deployment
    uses: bobheadxi/deployments@v1
    if: always()
    with:
      step: finish
      token: ${{ secrets.BUILDBOT_PERSONAL_TOKEN }}
      status: ${{ job.status }}
      env: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.env }}
      deployment_id: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.deployment_id }}
```

Things I have verified:

- Vercel is properly linked to my-repo GitHub project.
- GitHub secrets are created to provide the Vercel project ID + org ID (the ones provided in the .vercel directory upon linking the my-repo project to Vercel).
- I disabled Vercel builds in my vercel.json file in my-repo so that only GitHub is doing the builds.

The logs don't provide any other information that I can find - any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Check what http calls `bobheadxi/deployments` makes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being that my secrets were not properly being fed into my GitHub Actions by the Buildbot I have set up.  Now that the secrets are properly configured, the same code does deploy to Vercel.

*face palm*

Answer (score 0):

LOL I had the same problem, here is fix inside workflow file (workflow.yml):

```
      - name: Run worklow
    env:
      SOME_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SOME_TOKEN }}
    working-directory: ./directory
    run: run command
```